# How to apply custom format (currency) to a textbox based in a combobox selection?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a combobox with different currency items: "PEN, USD, etc"
I have a textbox with an amount that I need it to have the corresponding currency symbol based on the selection of the combobox.

Not a solution:

If I use:
`TextBox1.Value = Format(TextBox1.Value, "$#,##0.00")` it shows the dollar symbol.

`TextBox1.Value = Format(TextBox1.Value, "[$S/-es-PE] #,##0.00")` it doesnt show the S/ symbol (corresponding to PEN) I coppied this format from when custom formating a cell in a sheet.

`TextBox1.Value = Format(TextBox1.Value, "currency")` it shows the regional configuration currency symbol.
I don't want to change my regional settings since this doesnt solve the problem. I want to be able to show different symbol according to the currency selected.

thanks!

Comment: How do you load the combo? From a range having the necessary format?

Comment: from a table. the combobox does not need to have format. because is just the name of the currency.

Comment: So, do you have in combo "USD" and need "$", "PEN" and need "P"? Is this what you want? If so, are there currencies needing to have the specific sign at the end of the string? The cell `NumberFormat` is not the same with the one returned by VBA `Format` function...

Comment: In the combo if I select "USD", in the textbox if I enter the value of 10, I should see $10.00. That's no problem. The problem is for other currencies. for "PEN" for example, I would expect to read S/.10.00. And this applies to any other currency. I don't want exotic symbols, I just want the symbols that excel already have when you apply custom format to a cell in a sheeet.

Comment: If you are able to make  an equivalence list between what combo shows and what you need in front of the number (like prefix), I can help you. I mean 'USD - $', 'PEN - S/.', 'EURO - € ' etc. Otherwise, I do not know any way of making the automate equivalence.

Comment: Those 3 are enough :), btw I just want the format, not the value to be changed. thanks in advanced

Comment: In a **text** box, the format notion does not exist. **Everything is text**! It only looks as you want. Do you want multiplying the textbox text, for instance? If so, you do not have any solution, I am afraid...

Comment: ok, lets try it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way. I tried to create a function to extract the value from the text. You can use it in order to make arithmetical operations with the text box value. Having a combo ("ComboBox1") and a text box ("TextBox1"), please paste the following code the combo box `Click` event:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
   Dim arrCur, arrEch, mtch
  arrC = Split("USD,PEN,EURO", ",") 'the string representation from combo, separated by comma (not by ", ")
  arrEch = Split("$,S/.,€ ", ",")   'the desired corresponding format string
  If Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then 'if a selection exists (in combo):
    If Me.TextBox1.Value <> "" Then    'if text box is  not empty:
        mtch = Application.match(Me.ComboBox1.Value, arrC, 0)
        Me.TextBox1.Value = arrEch(mtch - 1) & Format(numberPart(Me.TextBox1.Value), "#,##0.00")
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

You can add as many currencies as you need, **as comma separated** in `arrCur` array. And then the corresponding sign to appear as suffix, in `arrEch` array.
The next function is necessary to extract the numeric part and eliminate when change the format. It can be also used if you need to use the numeric part for other operations:

```
Private Function numberPart(strVal As String) As Currency
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(strVal)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(strVal, i, 1)) Then numberPart = CCur(Right(strVal, Len(strVal) - i + 1)): Exit Function
    Next i
End Function
```

You can use the same (first) array to load the combo, pasting the next code in the form 'Initialize`event. In such a case, it should be good to declare`arrCur`as a`Private`variable on top of the form module (in the declarations area) and just using it in the combo`Change` event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim arrCur, El
  arrC = Split("USD,PEN,EURO", ",")
  For Each El In arrC
     Me.ComboBox1.AddItem El
  Next
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: @Walter S. Escobedo Didn't you find some time to test the above solution? If tested, didn't it work as you need?

Comment: it worked as intended. I am new to VBA so there is maybe some code that I don't understand but I get the general idea. Thanks!